# Pager for query with many relations and fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a quite complex view with two queries (a view in a view), one select users with related data and another one select orders with related data. Both of them have some filters, but now I have an issue and I am looking for proper and just decent solution, with good performance because I have a lot of data and relationships in the queries.
Assume I have:

Query 1 - Select user data, some left joins to other tables, conditions depends on provided parameters.

Query 2 - Select orders depends on users from Query 1, many joins, conditions depends on parameters.

I display data from two queries in one view, users, their data, orders, and some orders data and now I want to implement pager, but it has to work and display proper number of users depends on filters form Query 1 and Query 2. So there is an issue that I can't really limit from any query cuz another one has filters as well so maybe those users maybe aren't really selected to display depends on other query filters.
So I guess there are two ways, one is to put those queries in loop and collect data until I get proper number of results depends on query.
Another way is to merge those two queries into one, but there an issue that I get many rows per user, so I can't set any page limit and get results only for specific number of users, like for example 30. Because results will be like user 1 => order 1, user 1 => order 2, so is there any way to get specific number of unique results depends on user id or something.
Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I'm stuck on your first sentence.  A `VIEW`, by definition, contains a single `SELECT`, not "two queries".

Comment: @RickJames yeah but I have a view in a view.

Comment: It's hard to talk about queries when I can't see them.  And the View.  And the View in the View.  And `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

Sample data will make more sense. I am unable to understand the whole requirement here in your question. will you be able to create some sample data and share with us ? if you are dealing with a lot of data, avoid loops as that will just make performance worse.